# In JMeter, how can I create multiple blocks of payload while selecting different values for each elements from CSV file?

Tags: jmeter

In the Sample below I need to send 1 to 10 blocks of `<ACCOUNT>` payload randomly *(the sample shows 4 blocks of `<ACCOUNT>` payload)*, while the elements `<ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE>`, `<OPEN_DATE>`, and `<MEMBER_ID>` need to select values either sequentially or randomly from CSV file. Even the same thread needs to pick different values for each block of `<ACCOUNT>` payload. How can I do that in JMeter? Thanks.

```
<IN xmlns:ns3="http://schema.example.com/queryparam" xmlns:ns2="http://schema.example.com/header" xmlns="http://schema.example.com/Account/CreateAC">
      <ns2:HEADER>
            <ns2:TRANID>hgjhkjhjkhjg</ns2:TRANID>
            <ns2:TIMESTAMP>2019-10-06T15:32:470Z</ns2:TIMESTAMP>
      </ns2:HEADER>
      <ns3:QUERY>
            <ns3:PARAM>
                  <ns3:ITEM>OPERATOR</ns3:ITEM>
                  <ns3:VALUE xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">CREATEAC</ns3:VALUE>
            </ns3:PARAM>
      </ns3:QUERY>

    <ACCOUNT_SPECIFIC>
            <ACCOUNT>
                <ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE>CD</ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE>
                <OPEN_DATE>2019-10-06</OPEN_DATE>
                <MEMBER_ID>68768789799<MEMBER_ID>
            </ACCOUNT>
            <ACCOUNT>
                <ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE>Checking</ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE>
                <OPEN_DATE>2019-10-05</OPEN_DATE>
                <MEMBER_ID>45667568797<MEMBER_ID>
            </ACCOUNT>            
            <ACCOUNT>
                <ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE>Saving</ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE>
                <OPEN_DATE>2019-10-04</OPEN_DATE>
                <MEMBER_ID>24535456677<MEMBER_ID>
            </ACCOUNT>
            <ACCOUNT>
                <ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE>Money Market</ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE>
                <OPEN_DATE>2019-10-03</OPEN_DATE>
                <MEMBER_ID>898977867554<MEMBER_ID>
            </ACCOUNT>          
    </ACCOUNT_SPECIFIC>
</IN>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have XML file which looks like:

```
CD,2019-10-06,68768789799
Checking,2019-10-05,45667568797
Saving,2019-10-04,24535456677
Money Market,2019-10-03,898977867554
```

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) which request body you want to parameterize
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
   import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils

   def writer = new StringWriter()
   def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)

   def csvFileLines = new File('test.csv').readLines()

   def lineCounter = 0

   xml.IN("xmlns:ns3": "http://schema.example.com/queryparam", "xmlns:ns2": "http://schema.example.com/header", "xmlns": "http://schema.example.com/Account/CreateAC") {
       "ns2:HEADER"() {
           ns2:
           TRANID("hgjhkjhjkhjg")
           ns2:
           TIMESTAMP("2019-10-06T15:32:470Z")
       }
       "ns3:QUERY"() {
           "ns3:PARAM"() {
               "ns3:ITEM"("OPERATOR")
               "ns3:VALUE "("CREATEAC")
           }
       }

       xml.ACCOUNT_SPECIFIC() {
           1.upto(RandomUtils.nextInt(1, 11), {
               def line = csvFileLines.get(lineCounter)
               def entries = line.split(",")
               ACCOUNT() {
                   ACCOUNT_TYPE_CODE(entries[0].trim())
                   OPEN_DATE(entries[1].trim())
                   MEMBER_ID(entries[2].trim())
               }
               lineCounter++
           })
       }
   }

   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', writer.toString(), '')
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
   ```
3. That's it, the above code will generate from 1 to 10 `ACCOUNT` blocks and set the generated data as the HTTP Request sampler body data. Overall test plan should look like:

   [image]

References:

- [Groovy: Creating XML](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_creating_xml)
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/)